# Xamarin. How to convert Android Java.Lang.String to System.String

Tags: java, string, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried `(string)str` and `str.ToString()`. It works but not properly. If originally there is `\"` then after casting `\\\"` appears.

Comment: What is the issue? You've converted a valid string to another string. The escape characters give you the correct string `\"`

Comment: @cricket_007 no actually, I don't know why but that's the result (There are extra backslash) {\"result\":{\"message\":null,\"authBearerToken\":\"h604tEXgh8acHByAXn5680fMfhvSPvJ72O9XkBvOX\"}}

Comment: What exactly is the original Java string?

Comment: {"\u003Cpre style=\"word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;\">{\"result\":{\"message\":null,\"authBearerToken\":\"yv7bsDUDtoxYdAEOQC6kovZsuqlq7L4U7sv-DOBm-ShWHEz3xH-6BVxo_6pZPB\"},\"targetUrl\":null,\"success\":true,\"error\":null,\"unAuthorizedRequest\":false,\"__abp\":true}\u003C/pre>"}

Comment: That is JSON. And JSON Strings also need escape characters. Unclear why you're putting HTML tags  into json, though

Comment: I fixed my problem with json = json.Replace("\\", "");
The original java string I get by EvaluateJavascript("document.body.innerHTML", this);
The problem was not in string casting but in evaluation that javascript

Comment: @cricket_007 That's not me. That's webView.

Comment: Okay, well, still a poor solution. You need to use a proper json parser client side or a proper json generator server side

Comment: @cricket_007 On server side everything is ok, because on iOS everything works. Webview adds additional markup to show json received from server and I can't do anything else but pulling json from html. I am doing login by google or facebook through webview

Comment: Alright, well, best of luck, I guess :) feel free to add your working solution as an answer below instead of leaving it in the comments

Comment: A simple test shows that the string stays the same after the conversion. Maybe you misinterpret what is shown by the debug visualizer?